# H2 DB Incorrect special characters sorting

Tags: java, database, h2, collate

I'm trying to sort column data in my h2 database, but it isn't correct.

[image]

I think that change of collation may help. I tried to set collation in datasource url in many ways e.g.:
`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;COLLATION='ENGLISH'`

`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;SET COLLATION='EN''`

`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;SET COLLATION ENGLISH STRENGTH PRIMARY'`

And I'm still have an syntax error like this `Syntax error in SQL statement "SET COLLATION 'ENGLISH'[*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
SET COLLATION 'ENGLISH' [42001-200]`

Am I doing something wrong? Or there is some other way to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, when I changed url to ```spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;COLLATION=POLISH``` app is working, but sorting is still incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2 Console uses browser's sorting capabilities provided by simple `Array.sort()`, they aren't affected by collation setting of H2. I created a feature request for this problem:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2694

The URL `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;COLLATION=POLISH` is correct. You can test that it works:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (VALUES 'AAAAAA', 'LLLLLLLLL', 'ZZZZZZ', 'ĄĄĄĄĄĄ', 'ŁŁŁŁŁŁ') T(V)
    ORDER BY V;
> V
> --------- 
> AAAAAA
> ĄĄĄĄĄĄ
> LLLLLLLLL
> ŁŁŁŁŁŁ
> ZZZZZZ
```

Without POLISH collation result will be just like on yours screenshot.

So the oblivious workaround is to append `ORDER BY BUILDINGS_NUMBER` to your query.

Note that there are different strength levels of collation. For example, for `SECONDARY` you can use `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;COLLATION=POLISH STRENGTH SECONDARY`. See documentation for more details:
https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_collation

Comment: Working, thanks!
Hmm, can you tell me what can I do to fix sorting like this?

```SELECT * FROM
    (VALUES '9B', '9A', '99A', '10') T(V)
    ORDER BY V DESC;
> V
> --------- 
> 9B
> 9A
> 99A
> 10
```
I should have 99A > 10 > 9B > 9A

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Character strings aren't sorted like numbers. If `V` always starts with a digit and number of digits isn't too large, try `ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(V, '[^0-9].*', '') AS INTEGER) DESC, V DESC` instead.

Comment: Its working in some examples, but when i have query like this ```SELECT * FROM     (VALUES '9B', '9A', '99A', '10', 'AAAA') T(V) ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(V, '[^0-9].*', '') AS INTEGER) DESC``` i have a data conversion error

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM (VALUES '9B', '9A', '99A', '10', 'AAAA') T(V) ORDER BY CAST(NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(V, '[^0-9].*', ''), '') AS INTEGER) DESC NULLS FIRST, V DESC`; don't forget about `V DESC` to sort 9B and 9A in predictable order. You may want to use `NULLS LAST` instead of `NULLS FIRST` depending on desired order of values without numbers. If you have very large numbers, use some larger data type instead of `INTEGER`, such as `BIGINT` or even `NUMERIC(100)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for bringing that in.
Had similar problem with my Quarkus application hooked to H2 database. Adding:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;COLLATION=POLISH
```

at my `application.properties` file solves the problem and all ORDER BY queries returning expected results.